# Writing simple FTP-like client/server app in C++

Tags: c++, sockets, networking, ftp

I'm hoping to write a simple FTP-like app, including both the client and the server in a Microsoft environment. I say FTP-like because I won't need to follow FTP protocol, I just want to build a client that can send a directory + file string to a server, and then have that server either send back the contents of the file, or send the file itself.

Right now my pseudo-code is something like this:

FTP Client:
- open socket 
- send file string to server
- other functionality as desired
- receive response

FTP Server:
- open socket
- new thread for every incoming connection
- receives file string
- checks to see if file string is in the right format and if the file exists
- sends response to client to tell if string was valid
- either open up and read text files, or transfer the file itself
- send file or contents of file back to client

Does that general skeleton make sense? Is there anything obvious that I might be missing? I was thinking that I might need one socket each for the status and transfer. Any tips or general direction on how to proceed further with this project would be appreciated.

Comment: Why won't you just follow ftp? It's pretty well established protocol that gets the job done.

Comment: Ideally I'd like the app to be as simple as possible. Completion is more important than functionality. I assume that and following the exact protocol would be mutually exclusive.

Comment: FTP is very simple protocol, with already out-there implementations that are blazing fast, battle tested and ready to be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up finishing the project after a good amount of research and rifling through other established FTP servers.

I did end up stripping down the project to a bare bones version but also used FTP protocol at a very basic level, which meant creating a socket to send commands, as well as a socket to send files.

So the basic structure of my app could recurse directories and send all files within the directory using those two sockets and a basic looping structure.